# Better way to perform same loop to populate two different collections c#

Tags: c#

Currently I have two distinct lists that need to have the same operation performed on each of them.

Is there a better way to do it than my current method of:

```
foreach (FileMatch fileName in lstChanged.Items)
{
    List<Symbol> fileOneSymbols = new List<Symbol>();
    List<Symbol> fileTwoSymbols = new List<Symbol>();
    foreach (List<Symbol> list in new[] { fileOneSymbols, fileTwoSymbols })
    {
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(list == fileOneSymbols ? _folderOne : _folderTwo + fileName.FilePath);
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            string line = lines[i];
            if (line.Contains("inst"))
            {
                list.Add(new Symbol(line, lines[i + 1], i + 1));
            }
        }
    }
    //Further Processing to go here
}
```

It's not a critical issue, I just don't like writing the same(ish) code twice and I know I could pull it out as a function and call that twice, but I'm just wondering if there's a better, less code smell way of doing this.

Comment: what you want to do inside the second loop

Comment: Create a seperate function for 2nd foreach

Comment: `listOne.Concat(listTwo)`?

Comment: To clarify, it's essentially the same operation on both lists but they need to be kept separate for later processing, I'll provide full (relevant) source in a moment

Comment: @JamesHughes that doesn't clarify much. If you just wanted to perform the same operation, why didn't you loop over each list using the same function inside the loop?

Comment: "I know I could pull it out as a function and call that twice" <-- what would be wrong with that approach?

Comment: Just concatenate the two lists.

Comment: @rory.ap nothing would be wrong with it, I'm just wondering if there's a better way that this that doesn't involve factoring it out as a function. Curiosity calling more than anything

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos -- That's less efficient than just calling an action or a method on the elements in the two lists consecutively, no?  Not sure how a concat works under the hood.  Does it just link the pointer from the end of one to the head of the next?

Comment: @JamesHughes -- Factoring it out as a function *is* a better way.  That's a preferred way always.  Smaller methods always win.

Comment: @rory.ap not sure what you refer to, but `concat` is just another Enumerable extension, so no pointers, just an enumerable that iterates over each of its sub-enumerables. Probably with a loop too. As for efficiency, just check the modified question. There is no iteration of the lists, it's *modification*

Comment: Fair one @rory.ap I just thought it would be pointless cluttering up my codebase with more methods when this will never be used again (roll on c#7 local functions)

Comment: @JamesHughes your edit doesn't make sense any more. You don't iterate over the list contents, you modify them. You don't need local functions. You need a drastic refactoring. *Reverse* the order of evaluation. *Create* the results, then collect them in a list or whatever you want them to be

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos what's wrong with populating two lists as you create the entries?

Comment: Maybe I wasn't very clear with my initial example...

Comment: https://advancedweb.hu/2017/11/21/a_detailed_case_study_against_for/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should extract a seperate method:

```
private IEnumerable<Symbol> _getSymbolsFromFile(string fileName)
{      
      string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
      for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
      {
          string line = lines[i];
          if (line.Contains("inst"))
              yield return new Symbol(line, lines[i + 1], i + 1);
      }
}
```

then call it in your loop like this:

```
List<Symbol> fileOneSymbols = _getSymbolsFromFile(_folderOne + fileName.FilePath).ToList();
List<Symbol> fileTwoSymbols = _getSymbolsFromFile(_folderTwo + fileName.FilePath).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var list1= new List<string>(); 
  // manipulate list1
 var list2= new List<string>();
    // manipulate list2
 var MainList= new List<string>();
 MainList.AddRange(list1);
 MainList.AddRange(list2);
 MainList.ForEach(t=>{
  // do your action
 });
```

Comment: *Why* copy the lists? Anyway, you'll notice that the question mentions looping but does *not* actually loop over the lists. It *fills* them inside the inner action

Comment: so you can add one of list to other then run loop on it

Answer (score 0):

You mention looping over lists, yet your code doesn't do that. In fact, the lists are empty at the start, filled by the inner loop itself, based on which list is being processed. You could simplify your code a *lot* if moved in a logical way:

Process your folders, files, filter the lines and create a list of the results.

You can create a simple method that receives the folder as input and returns a list of symbols. If you want the data to look :

```
IEnumerable<Symbol> SymbolsFromFolder(string file)
{
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length-1; i++)
    {
        string line = lines[i];
        if (line.Contains("inst"))
        {
            yield return new Symbol(line, lines[i + 1], i + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

The full code can become:

```
foreach (FileMatch fileName in lstChanged.Items)
{
    var symbolsOne= SymbolsFromFolder(Path.Combine(_folderOne, fileName.FilePath);
    var symbolsTwo= SymbolsFromFolder(Path.Combine(_folderTwo, fileName.FilePath);
//Further Processing to go here
}
```

If you wanted to tread all symbols as one, you could return everything in a single list:

```
var folders=new[]{_folderOne,folderTwo}
var allSymbols=from FileMatch fileName in lstChanged.Items
               from folder in folders
               let symbols=SymbolsFromFolder(Path.Combine(_folderOne, fileName.FilePath)
               from symbol in symbols
               select symbol;
```